# Error Message Problem : "Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.VariantTransformConfigurationException"

Tags: runtime-error

can I get assistanc in resolving the following error message I have been getting trying to run one of the sample app in the Android studio?

Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.VariantTransformConfigurationException: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@205030d0 of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator

I imported Crame Sample project into Adroid studio with the intention to run it but keep getting the above error codes.

Quick resolution of this will help me a great deal in advancing my knowledge of Adroid Studio.

Thanks for the anticipated timely response

Answer (score 1):

1. Clean gradle with command `./gradlew clean`.
2. Run AssembleDebug command `./gradlew assembleDebug`
   This will print missing SDK or SDK-Tools to download which is causing issue to build.
3. Download the missing SDK or SDK-Tools and try to build again.